How to enable DevTools remote debugging on chrome
Trying to run selenum with ruby and getting below error
DevTools remote debugging is disallowed by the system admin
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class SeleniumPoc
  def setup
    #options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.chrome(accept_insecure_certs: true)
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    


    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') # To handle insecure certificates
    options.accept_insecure_certs = true  # Accept insecure certificates
    #options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.chrome(accept_insecure_certs: true)
    #options.args << '--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests'
    #options.args << '--ignore-certificate-errors'


    @my_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

    @url = 'www.google.com'
    puts 'getting url'
    @my_driver.get(@url)

    sleep 5

 

  end
end

obj = SeleniumPoc.new()
obj.setup

enter image description here

any reason you are setting the debugging port?  I'd remove that option and try again.
